# How do I count the number of strings in a data frame regardless of ordering of elements?

Tags: r, count, dplyr, duplicates

I am trying to count the number of character strings with a certain grouping of elements, regardless of ordering. I've seen some answers that discuss how to remove them or how to find out if they are equal to each other but I need a count of them.

Example data set (items packed for travel):

```
Person    Month    Item
Adam        1      Shoe
Adam        1       Hat
Frank       1       Hat
Frank       1       Shoe
```

I'm using `packing <- group_by(Person, Month) %>% summarise_all(funs(toString(unique(.))))` to get

```
Person     Month    Item
Adam        1       Shoe, Hat
Frank       1       Hat, Shoe
```

Then I use `grouped_packing <- packing %>% group_by(Item) %>% summarise(count=n())`

R gives me a count of 1 for each list, when really I want it to ignore the ordering and tell me I have 2 of the same list. How can I do this?

EDIT: Adding more data

```
Person    Month    Item
Adam        1      Shoe
Adam        1       Hat
Frank       1       Hat
Frank       1       Shoe
Sally       2       Shoe
Sally       2       Hat
Sally       2       Shoe
Sally       2       Hat
Jen         3       Belt
Jen         4       Belt
```

Grouped:

```
Person     Month    Item
Adam        1       Shoe, Hat
Frank       1       Hat, Shoe
Sally       2       Shoe, Hat
Sally       2       Shoe, Hat
Jen         3       Belt
Jen         3       Belt
```

I want to end up with the result:

```
Item Groups     N
Shoe, Hat       4
Belt            2
```

Would this change the approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along the lines of @NelsonGon's answer using `n()`, you'll want to count before you summarize:

```
library(tidyverse)

packing <- tribble(
  ~Person,    ~Month,    ~Item,
  "Adam",        1,       "Shoe",
  "Adam",        1,       "Hat",
  "Frank",       1,       "Hat",
  "Frank",       1,       "Shoe" 
)

packing %>% 
  group_by(Person, Month) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(N = n(), Item = toString(unique(.))))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   Person [?]
  Person Month     N Item     
  <chr>  <dbl> <int> <chr>    
1 Adam       1     2 Shoe, Hat
2 Frank      1     2 Hat, Shoe
```

Per @IceCreamToucan's astute comment, if your `Items` within each  `Person` and `Month` are not unique, you could end up with a  result that has an `N` larger than the apparent length of your comma-separated-item-list(for lack of a  better term). You could use `N = length(unique(.))` to avoid this.

To answer your edited question:

```
packing %>% 
  group_by(Person, Month) %>% 
  arrange(Item) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(N = n(), Item = toString(unique(.)))) %>%
  ungroup %>% group_by(Item) %>%
  summarize(N = n())

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Item          N
  <chr>     <int>
1 Belt          2
2 Hat, Shoe     3
```

You'll need to sort with `arrange` first in order to avoid the same list being permuted different ways. Then remove the remaining grouping, re-group with `Item` and summarize appropriately.

As an aside, "list" is a very special word in R, hence the confusion before your initial edit. It may be worth checking out [this section from Hadley Wickham's R for Data Science book](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/vectors.html#lists) if you'd like to explore further.

Comment: This is very helpful! Thanks zack. And yes, I realized list wasn't the right word to use for this :D

Follow up question. What if after running the code you provided, I end up with a third row that has Sally, 2, 1, Shoe, Hat. I want to know that there were 3 "Shoe/Hat" combos.. How would I do that? If I group by Item and sum, I'd get 5 which would duplicate the numbers

Comment: I added a more detailed example to my original post

Comment: updated the answer - essentially just sorting and re-grouping

Comment: Amazing! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mutate` instead of `summarise`:

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Item,Month) %>% 
 mutate(N=n())

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   Item, Month [2]
  Person Month Item      N
  <chr>  <int> <chr> <int>
1 Adam       1 Shoe      2
2 Adam       1 Hat       2
3 Frank      1 Hat       2
4 Frank      1 Shoe      2
```

Comment: If I had another row with Sally, 1, Shoe - would that make the N for Shoe 3 for all of them? Because I want 2 for Adam/Frank but 1 for Sally. Since that's a unique grouping.

Comment: You can group by Person too(can't test). Currently away from my computer.

Comment: If you add `Person` as a grouping variable (similar to zacks response) it should give you the sum of items for Sally (edit: as Nelson just pointed out as well).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution using `tapply()` from base `R`

```
attach(packing)  # attach the data frame
tapply(Item, list(Person, Month), function(x) length(unique(x)))

      1
Adam  2
Frank 2
```